# Expectation of random variable $f(w) = w$.

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Expectation of random variable $f(w) = 1-w$.

Is this right?

$Fx(x) = \mu_f$

$ \left\{\begin{matrix}
\mu(\emptyset) = 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ for \ x < 0 \\ 
\mu([1-x,1)) =  x \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ for \ \ 0 \leq x \leq 1\\ 
\mu([0,1]) = 1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \  \ for \ x > 1
\end{matrix}\right.$

So
$$E(f) = {\int_\Omega f(w) \mu_f(dw) = \int_R f(w) \mu_f(dw)}$$
$$=\int_R (1-x) \mu_f(dx) $$
$$=\int_{[0,\infty)} (1-x) \mu_f(dx) $$
$$=1 \mu_f([0,\infty)) -x[0,\infty) = 1-x$$

Comment: The answer cannot be dependent by $x$.

Comment: The first line contradicts the title.